# C++ Qt Game Dev: How to instantiate game objects at a specific positions read from a txt file?

Tags: c++, qt, game-development

I am trying to add a functionality to a game. First, here's a description of what was the initial version of the game like:

**What I Had at Hand**

I had at hand, a simple baloon popping game where the balloons enter the screen from above at randomly generated x coordinates (and fixed y=60 y coordinate) and start moving downwards. If the player clicks on a balloon before the balloon goes out of bound, he scores. If the balloon goes out of bound before being clicked, the player misses. There is a time counter starting from 30seconds and if the counter reaches 0, the game shows a message screen displaying the hits, misses and the final score(hit-miss) of the player.

[Here's how the game looked previously. On the top, there are counters: Süre(tr:time), Vurulan Balon Sayısı(tr:hits), Kaçırılan Balon Sayısı(tr:misses)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqqHU.jpg)

**What Functionality I am Trying to Add**

Initially, the game generates balloons always at:

y=60 and x=(a random x variable within the bounds of the game screen)

But I want the game to read a text file named konumlar.txt(tr:coordinates.txt) with two numbers in each of its lines, seperated by a space (' ') where the first number is an x-coordinate and the second number is a y-coordinate. Then the program should store each line's coordinate info as a tuple, and form a list from those tuples. This list of coordinates in my implementation is called coordinatePool. Whenever a balloon is to be generated, the program should choose one coordinate from this coordinatePool and generate it there. In my implementation, I stored the coordinates in QPoints and those QPoints in a QList.

**What Problem Did I Encounter**

Upon doing my implementation and running the program, I saw that balloons are not generated correctly. Namely, balloons seemed to be generated only from the top left corner of my game screen. And there were balloons here and there, visible for a split second then disappearing.

[the balloons only generate at the left side of the game screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE3CG.jpg)

**My Source Code**

balon.cpp:

```
#include "balon.h"
balon::balon(QWidget *win,int x, int y)
{
    scrsize = win->size();
    balon_num = QRandomGenerator::global()->bounded(0, 7);
    label = new QLabel(win);
    path = QString(":/images/images/") + QString::number(balon_num) + ".jpg";
    pic.load(path);
    label->setGeometry(x, y, 50, 50);
    label->setPixmap(pic.scaled(50, 50, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
    label->installEventFilter(this);
    label->show();
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setInterval(15);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(status(int)), win, SLOT(checkstatus(int)));
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(move()));
    connect(win, SIGNAL(focusin()), this, SLOT(start()));
    connect(win, SIGNAL(focusout()), this, SLOT(stop()));
    timer->start();
}
void balon::move() {
    scrsize = label->parentWidget()->size();
    if (label->y() >= scrsize.height() - 30) {
        emit status(0);
        delete label;
        delete this;
    } else {
        label->setGeometry(x, label->y() + 3, 50, 50);
        timer->start();
    }

}
bool balon::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e){
    if (o == label && e->type() == QMouseEvent::MouseButtonPress) {
        clicked();
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(o,e);
}

void balon::clicked() {
    delete timer;
    emit status(1);
    label->removeEventFilter(this);
    pic2.load(":/images/images/patlama.jpg");
    label->setPixmap(pic2.scaled(50, 50, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(destroy()));
}
void balon::destroy(){
    delete label;
    delete this;
}
void balon::stop(){
    if (!stopped) {
        timer->stop();
        stopped = true;
    }
}
void balon::start(){
    if (stopped) {
        timer->start();
        stopped = false;
    }
}
```

part of the mainwindow.cpp where i read the txt file and generate balloons:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "balon.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QString>
#include <QDir>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QList>
#include <QScreen>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    QFile file(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/konumlar.txt");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        QTextStream in(&file);
        while (!in.atEnd()) {
            QString line = in.readLine();
            QStringList coordinates = line.split(" ");
            if (coordinates.size() >= 2) {
                int x = coordinates.at(0).toInt();
                int y = coordinates.at(1).toInt();
                coordinatePool.push_back(QPoint(x, y));
                qDebug()<< coordinatePool;
            }
        }
        file.close();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Failed to open konumlar.txt";
    }

    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->centralwidget->setLayout(ui->verticalLayout_2);
    this->showMaximized();
    this->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    time2 = 30;
    timer2 = new QTimer(this);
    timer2->setInterval(1000);
    connect(timer2, &QTimer::timeout, [this](){
        time2--;
        ui->label_3->setNum(time2);
        if (time <= 0){
            endGame();
        }
    });
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(generate()));

    int index = QRandomGenerator::global()->bounded(0,coordinatePool.size());
    new balon(this,coordinatePool.at(index).x(),coordinatePool.at(index).y());
    timer->start(500);
    timer2->start();
}
void MainWindow::generate()
{
    if (coordinatePool.isEmpty()){
        qDebug()<<"No coordinates available";
        return;
    }

    int index = QRandomGenerator::global()->bounded(0,coordinatePool.size());
    QPoint coordinate = coordinatePool.at(index);
    new balon(this,coordinate.x(),coordinate.y());
    time = QRandomGenerator::global()->bounded(400,1000);
    timer->start(time);
}

}
```

Finally, konumlar.txt:

```
100 200
200 300
500 500
150 100
1000 100
1100 150
300 200
800 250
900 300
400 350
550 400
600 200
700 200
1200 150
800 300
100 100
150 100
200 100
250 200
350 200
700 230
300 100
1000 500
1000 550
1000 600
400 700
450 100
550 100
900 100
800 400
```

**What did I Thought/Try?**

Initially, I thought that the program couldnt form the coordinate tuples QPoints and the list of QPoints, QList incorrectly. But I wrote some debug code and here's the QList that my program creates:

`QList(QPoint(100,200), QPoint(200,300), QPoint(500,500), QPoint(150,100), QPoint(1000,100), QPoint(1100,150), QPoint(300,200), QPoint(800,250), QPoint(900,300), QPoint(400,350), QPoint(550,400), QPoint(600,200), QPoint(700,200), QPoint(1200,150), QPoint(800,300), QPoint(100,100), QPoint(150,100), QPoint(200,100), QPoint(250,200), QPoint(350,200), QPoint(700,230), QPoint(300,100), QPoint(1000,500), QPoint(1000,550), QPoint(1000,600), QPoint(400,700), QPoint(450,100), QPoint(550,100), QPoint(900,100), QPoint(800,400))`

Then, I looked at my gamescreen's size and try to find if coordinates in konumlar.txt were out of bound, but the size was something like 1580x850, so coordinates seem to be within the bounds. Then I created a QPoint with coordinates (750,750) and painted a circle around it to see what will happen. Oddly, only the part of the circle that falls outside of the backscreen game texture was visible, and the circle was formed on the up left corner of the screen.

Then I lifted the ui element that was the wooden background texture of my game and ran the game again, and no balloons were generated behind that ui element. But i suspect that my program tries to create the balloons behind that ui element. I must say, I am not good at explaining the details in a technical level.

What could be the problem? I am ready to share every file/screenshot required.

Comment: Please consider posting to [gamedev.se] since your post is game oriented.

Comment: Put a breakpoint right after this line and examine what `index` and `coordinate` are. You could also log them out if you like. See if that matches your expectations. I'd also reduce your text file to just a few coordinates so you can easily try and match them up.

Comment: You might also do a diff from the version that was using random coordinates and worked to what you have now. Perhaps you changed something by mistake. If you are not using source control you now have a very good reason to start.

Comment: `QPoint coordinate = coordinatePool.at(index);` is the line I was talking about checking in `generate`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I did a diff from the older version, nothing was changed by mistake. I logged out "index" and "coordinate". Both are working just fine and index retrieves the correct pair of integers from the coordinate list. Somewhere on here, i read that QList was never intended to store QPoints and that it is a bad practice to do so. Do you think it has relevance with my case? I tried to use QVector but nothing changed. I also tried to read my file in the main.cpp, before the mainwindow is created.

Comment: Might be an idea to paste the code necessary to build and reproduce the problem then someone could then help from there? Might also be worth simplifying the drawing region to exclude anything other than the circles to determine whether the problem is due to 'overlapping' graphical elements.

Comment: Seems odd that it used to work with random coordinates and doesn't with correct fixed coordinates loaded from the file. I wonder if you went back to random coordinates if it would still be broken. *shrug*

Comment: @BerkTezcan That's unlikely. The advice to prefer QVector (or std::vector more generally) is based on the fact that it has the best performance under typical circumstances. That is, its memory layout allows for fast random access and is also beneficial for repeated iteration over its elements.